# Why RabbitMQ connection failes on linux, but works on windows?

Tags: c#, linux, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm using a connection to a RabbitMQ. I develop on Windows and here it works. When I start on Linux I'm getting a exception:

> None of the specified endpoints were reachable at    at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)

..at the last line from the code below:

```
string uri = $"amqps://{userName}:{password}@{hostName}:{port}/{virtualHost}";
factory.Uri = new Uri(uri);
IConnection RMQConnection = null;
RMQConnection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

**What could cause these exceptions?**

Comment: My guess is that the Windows box can see (has access to) the RabbitMQ machine, and the Linux machine can't.

Comment: @mjwills The value is on both machines the same.
Before I used the access to a other RabbitMQ successfully, but now I changes to a other RabbitMQ connection (on the same machine) and this time with secure access ("amqps://").

Comment: I'm not used to linux so much.
When I do  ping ZDEOKO04SKRMQ02.deoko.zeiss.org 5671, I get the response: PING 5671 (0.0.22.39) 56(124) bytes of data., 16 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 14999ms. As I know there must be a space on linux between url and port, right? And the response does not look good.

Comment: @mjwills Yes. But the port works on windows and the port in necessary for the secure connection. Why the port does not work on linux?

Comment: It could be hundreds of reasons. Maybe your network admin blocked machine A from communicating with machine B over port C. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the security certificate was missing on the linux machine. (I used amqp**s**.)